# On Vue 2 : You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors

Tags: vuejs2, google-maps-api-3

On vue 2 am using the google maps api. its working fine but when i reload the page.that error occurred 'You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.'
main.js file
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, { load: { key: myKey', libraries: 'places' } });

am using the vuejs2 and googlemapsapi .
googlemapsapi version: "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7"

Component code :
`<div class="input-box" ><label for="country_id">Location</label> <gmap-autocomplete class="introInput"  @place_changed="setPlace"  placeholder="Search"  :value="location" > </gmapautocomplete</div>`

Main.js

`Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, { load: { key: myKey', libraries: 'places' } });`

when i reload that component this error trigger .Map and autocomplete stop working.
On live i notice in network the googlemapsapi loading from cache disk.

[image]
@Nathan Beck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please provide more details, including the template code and any relevant javascript in proper format

Comment: am using the vuejs2 and googlemapsapi .
googlemapsapi version: "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7"

Code Base 
 `<div class="input-box" >
      <label for="country_id">Location</label>
      <gmap-autocomplete 
       class="introInput" 
       @place_changed="setPlace" 
       placeholder="Search" 
       :value="location" 
       > 
       </gmap-autocomplete>
     </div>`
Main.js
`Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, { load: { key: myKey', libraries: 'places' } });`

when i reload that component this error trigger .Map and autocomplete stop working.

@Nathan Beck

Comment: thanks -- please update your question directly with the code -- it is not readable in a comment

Comment: what does index.html look like?

Comment: Its too long.. but i have not added googlemapsapi script in index.html.